# is there a git fetch + checkout in one action

Tags: git

I know git **pull** is equal to git **fetch**  + git **merge**

Is there a standard command that combines git **fetch**  & git **checkout**  ,
for downloading & switching to another branch that doesn't exist locally yet?

Comment: if you don't have the branch locally checked out, git checkout will not fetch "other branches" but will certainly bring the "HEAD" of the branch you're checking out.

Comment: Sounds like an alias to me